# Error trying to find JVM: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/usr/java'

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

i am trying to run and debug the Small app with spring boot and react, but i got this error:

**Error trying to find JVM: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/usr/java'**

i searched for the solution but didnt find any hints.

Could anyone please give me a hint or help? i would appreciate that. Underneath is my code on GitHub

thanks in Advance

[backend spring boot](https://github.com/vancouver29/EmployeeManager/tree/master/backend)

Comment: provide some insight or a bit more clarification what you were doing and trying to achieve

Comment: i am using Visual code Studio with Maven Dependencies : Springfox-swagger-ui, Srpingfox-swagger2., mysql, jpa. I used Docker mysql for the database Setup. i am trying just to run the code firstly before Doing the further steps

Comment: you might also get an error while using lombok with jpa check the issue i created on your repository i did it too but without docker but using sts

Answer (score 0):

Check for errors in your environment variables such as JAVA_HOME, JDK_HOME, etc

Comment: Also whether the editor specifies the Java work path (environment variable), such as the setting of the Spring Boot Tool in VS Code specifies the Java work path.